# Reaching shard data distributing in multiple Postgres servers in R

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, dplyr

I have 3 shard databases in 3 different Postgres servers and I am trying to connect these servers and write a sql to return a value in R. I can connect and write the query for the first one but I need the result of data from the three tables together. What should I do for that?

```
require("RPostgreSQL")
library(DBI)
library('dplyr')

# password
pw <- "postgres"

# loads the PostgreSQL driver
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

# creates a connection to the postgres database
con1 <- dbConnect(
  drv,
  dbname = "postgres",
  host = "0.0.0.0",
  port = 5436,
  user = "postgres",
  password = pw
)
con2 <- dbConnect(
  drv,
  dbname = "postgres",
  host = "0.0.0.0",
  port = 5431,
  user = "postgres",
  password = pw
)
con3 <- dbConnect(
  drv,
  dbname = "postgres",
  host = "0.0.0.0",
  port = 5436,
  user = "postgres",
  password = pw
)
rm(pw) # removes the password


# check for connection
dbExistsTable(con1, "shard1")
dbExistsTable(con2, "shard2")
dbExistsTable(con3, "shard3")
# TRUE

# the amount of paid installs by company, which happened in May
query = "SELECT company, SUM(installs)
FROM shard1
WHERE paid= 'TRUE' AND to_char(created_at,'mm')='05'
GROUP BY company"
dsub = tbl(con1, sql(query))
dsub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply row bind all the resulting data frames. Since names change in 1-2-3 pattern, use `get()` on the connection object and string interpolation for table name in SQL query, both dynamically referenced using `paste0`:

```
# RETURN LIST DATA FRAMES FOR EACH CONNECTION
df_list <- lapply(c(1:3), function(i) {

      query <- "SELECT company, SUM(installs) AS total_installs
                FROM %s
                WHERE paid = 'TRUE' 
                  AND to_char(created_at,'mm')='05'
                GROUP BY company"

      dbGetQuery(get(paste0("con", i)), sprintf(query, paste0("shard", i)))
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)     # BASE R CHAIN APPEND METHOD
# final_df <- bind_rows(df_list)        # DPLYR CHAIN APPEND METHOD
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer but I got an ERROR:  relation "shard1" does not exist
LINE 2:           FROM shard1. In con2 it should be shard2 and con3 shard3 how should I modify it?

Comment: See edit where now SQL query must be dynamically interpolated.

Comment: Super only rbind doesnt work for sum. I changed it to:   
final_df <-bind_rows(df_list) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
And works thank you very muchh

Comment: Hmmm...if data frame columns are exactly the same name within list of data frames, `rbind` should work.